# Post Meta statement?

Tags: php, post-meta

I have a Post meta field in my template. I have 3 values for this meta:

1. Yes
2. No
3. N/a

How can I set a custom css class according to the value ?

My code:

```
<span class="widget_last"><?php echo get_post_meta($post['ID'], 'Type', true); ?></span>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an [`if`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) or [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement to check the value of the meta, then echo out a different class name based on the value:

```
<?php
$type = get_post_meta($post['ID'], 'Type', true);

switch ( $type ) {
    case 'Yes':
        $class = 'type-yes';
        break;
    case 'No':
        $class = 'type-no';
        break;
    default:
        $class = 'type-na';
        break;
}
?>

<span class="widget_last <?php echo $class; ?>"><?php echo $type; ?></span>
```

Now you can style each type with `.widget_last.type-yes`, `.widget_last.type-no`, or `.widget_last.type-na`.

Comment: Thank you @Jacob, but I have an error: "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Post as array". 
The line is "$type = get_post_meta($post['ID'], 'Type', true);"

Comment: That line was just copied from your code so it shouldn't be behaving any differently. The first argument for `get_post_meta()` needs to be a post ID. How to get that depends on the context.

Comment: My bad, I had misplaced the code in my file. thank you again !